# IFrame not loading with mootools

Tags: javascript, iframe, mootools

im trying to get a youtubevideo loaded in an IFrame, but it just wont work. Am I missing something here?

```
addVideo.addEvent('click', function() {
link = ytlink.get('value');
src = new URI(link);
if(src.get('host') == 'www.youtube.com') {
    var videoFrame = new IFrame({
        url: 'http://'+src.get('host')+'/embed/'+src.get('data').v,
        styles: {
            width: 490,
            height: 276
        },
        events: {
            onLoad: function() {console.log('fertich');}
        }
    });
    container.grab(videoFrame);
}
```

addVideo is a link and i was lucky using the grab method til until now.
What is going wrong here? Anything apreciated.

edit: i want the youtube player to show up in the IFrame, but there is nothing in there (though an IFrame element is rendered into the page). Even not if i set `url` to `http://www.google.com/`.

This is the IFrame element created:

```
<iframe url="http://www.google.de" style="width: 490px; height: 276px; " name="IFrame_haxso5aq" id="IFrame_haxso5aq"></iframe>
```

cheers!

Comment: Won't work? What is the error message/wrong behavior? What is the actual behavior? Every question should have those two _details_ in it

Comment: Im sorry, it was a bit late yesterday. The youtubevideo wont load into the IFrame. Im getting an IFrame element rendered as the last child of `container`, a div element, but there is nothing inside the IFrame. The expected content wont show up even if i set the `url` property to `http://www.google.com/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is iFrame attribute you need not 'src' instead of 'url'?

```
var videoFrame = new IFrame({
    src: 'http://'+src.get('host')+'/embed/'+src.get('data').v,
    styles: {
        width: 490,
        height: 276
    },
    events: {
        onLoad: function() {console.log('fertich');}
    }
});
```

Comment: Holy crap. i was too sure using `url` as its attribute used in mootools `Request`. This did the trick. Thank you.